# How we fetch Onclick Button value in Cards recylerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardslib

It show an Null Object error.
    When i am fetching an Button Value on card RecylerView

```
Process: com.softedge.visioneering.tfd, PID: 9884
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
                      at com.softedge.visioneering.tfd.adapters.MyOrdersAdapter$MyOrdersViewHolder$1.onClick(MyOrdersAdapter.java:138)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5609)

This Is My Adapter and Button Code:

public class MyOrdersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtOrderDescription, txtOrderQuantity, txtOrderStatus, txtOrderDate, txtExpectedDate, txtCreatedBy,txtOrderStatus_Per;
String check;
        public Button update_btwn;
        public MyOrdersViewHolder(View convertView) {
            super(convertView);
            update_btwn=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status_update_button);

            final FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();

            update_btwn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     id = (Integer) update_btwn.getTag();

                   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Status_update_Fragment().newInstance()).addToBackStack(" ").commit();
                    //((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    // remove(((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container)).commit();

                }

            });
```

I want to perform an Action on Button.
Which is place in Cards RecylerView

Comment: You need to setTag right before getting it..

Comment: How we do it please tell me

Comment: I just want to know which button is press in card recylerView

Comment: `update_btwn.setTag("uniqueId/name")` like this tag & get that tag onClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `setTag()` in the `onBindViewHolder` method of your adapter:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
       viewHolder.mCardView.setTag(position);
   }
   ```

where `mCardView` is defined in the `myViewHolder` class.

```
private class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
           public View mCardView;

           public myViewHolder(View view) {
               super(view);
               mCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

               mCardView.setOnClickListener(this);
           }
       }
```

2. Use `getTag()` in your `OnClickListener` implementation:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
           int position = (int) view.getTag();           

       //display toast with position of cardview in recyclerview list upon click
       Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),Integer.toString(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the tag on the button?

You can either call `.setTag()` or in xml `android:tag=""`.

Also, you shouldn't set the click listener in the constructor of the view holder, do it in `onBindViewHolder`.